# What loss function must be used in case of binary outputs Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is my code where I am running multi layer LSTM:

```
layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons, 
                                 activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, use_peepholes = True)
         for layer in range(n_layers)]
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
outputs = outputs[:,n_steps-1,:] # keep only last output of sequence

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(outputs, y)) # loss function = mean squared error 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

As you can see I am using the Root Mean Square Error function for directing my LSTM. The output what I am getting is in between 0 and 1 which is not exactly what I was expecting. My guess is that this is happening because my error function is not correct for the operation.

I am expecting the output of the training must be in between 0 and 0.5 and 0.5 and 1. But the output is weird. It come around 0.9 and 1, which is not correct. Ultimately I am getting the mean of all. But that is not what I am expecting as correction or loss function. Please guide me what can be the best error function for my scenario.

Comment: Are you working on a binary classification problem? Logistic loss function is usually used in such a case. RMSE is normally used in regression problem.

Comment: Not exactly a binary classification but you may say like that, but not exact. As you see I am not expecting the output as 0 or 1 exactly but  like 0 to 0.5 and 0.5 to 1. But you may say the problem is like that.

Comment: Why not convert it into a binary classification problem by translating the target label in your data <= 0.5 to 0 and > 0.5 to 1 and then use logistic loss?

Comment: I tried that one it was not working. Hence  made it that way what it is currently.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried that? For your current situation if it is predicted all the values between 0.9 and 1, it is possible that you have a lot of data which is greater than 0.5 and the model is overfitting it. Did you measure the accuracy after the training?

Comment: May be that is the reason. But it is not avoidable in my case. The situation of lot of data greater 0.5 may arise. How would I know whether the mode is overfit or not. It seems all Okay to me till now

Comment: If you have some test data, you should measure the model's accuracy on the test data and compare it with the accuracy on the training data. An overfit model would have a very high accuracy on the training data while a poor or not so good accuracy on the test data. Some people even measure the accuracy every few batch.

Comment: Ok I will try it out.. May be some mistake on my side, I forgot something....